# Why matrix multiplication can be considered as function composition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Why matrix multiplication can be considered as function composition?

**My guess is:**

Because in its calculation we form a matrix by multiplication and then we add. If I am correct, I just need to see a concise proof for that.

Also, I want to understand why $(M_{n}(\mathbb{R}))$ does not have inverses?

Could anyone help me in clarifying those points, please?

Comment: Do you already know how to associate a function to a matrix?

Comment: @Mindlack I do not think so.

Comment: A matrix is a way to denote a linear map, given bases of the domain and of the codomain, and when you check how the composition of two linear maps corresponds to a matrix, it induces the way  the product of matrices is defined. On the other hand not all square matrices haverses  because invertible matrices correspond to bijective linear maps, and not all linear maps are bijective.

Comment: @Bernard for the second part of your comment, an example of it is the zero square matrix? but what linear map corresponds to the zero square matrix?

Comment: When we multiply a vector by a matrix we have mapped the vector to a new vector in a possibly different vector space.  This is a linear map, and linear maps meet the required definition of a function.  If we multiply by yet another matrix, we will then map the previous result to yet one more vector, in possibly yet another vector space.

Comment: @Bernard for the first part of your comment, can you give me a concrete example please? and a general proof?

Comment: @Smart20: Yes, and any matrix with a $0$ determinant, since it means the corresponding linear map has a non-trivial kernel.

Comment: It would be a bit long, but you can look at [Square Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_matrix) on Wikipedia, and ask any question if you meet problems. A good classical book reference is Serge Lang's *Introduction to Linear Algebra*.

Comment: Another way of looking at it ... the question you ask about composition and matrix mltipication is just a higher dimensional version of this: Let $f(x)=ax$ and $g(x)=bx$. Then $f(g(x)) = a(bx) = (ab)x$. So coefficient multiplication corresponds to composition of linear functions, and in higher dimensions, the role of the coefficient is played by a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, having looked at the comments, I'd like to provide an answer to your question about what linear transformation corresponds to the zero matrix.  Not surprisingly, it is the zero transformation, or the one that maps everything to zero.

Next, it is a rather neat fact that matrix multiplication corresponds to function composition.  Upon reflection, it must.  For as I believe @Bernard commented, it turns out that any linear transformation can be represented by multiplication by a matrix.

(Incidentally, to find such a matrix, just apply the linear transformation to the elements of a basis, and express the results in terms of any other basis.  The results will be the columns of the linear transformation's matrix relative to the two bases.)

As for inverses, a linear transformation is a kind of function.  And only injective functions have inverses.  So, the example above, that takes everything to zero, fails to have one (unless the domain is the zero vector space, in which case everything is quite trivial).  In the case of linear transformations, invertibility can be seen to be equivalent to having trivial kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Well, lets think of it another way. I could define a real function $f_n(x)=nx$ for all $n \in \mathbb{R}$. In this context $f_n(f_m(x))=f_n(mx)=nmx=f_{mn}(x)$. Now am I doing function composition or is this merely multiplication with additional notation? This in fact the one dimensional case with the matrix being represented by $m$ and $n$ and they act on the vectors $x$, all of which are just real numbers.

So we have two ways to approach this, one as multiplication and the other as function composition. Linear maps generalize this. How can we see that matrix multiplication in itself is a function? The core calculation is the dot product, which is certainly a function. Since each entry for each row and column are unambiguously defined by the rows and columns of the matrices being multiplied then matrix multiplication must be well-defined. This is why we're so picky about the size of the matrices being multiplied, to make sure the function exists.

As for notation, you can see why multiplication is often preferred to functional notation as it is simpler but there are many contexts where it's more useful to think of them as maps acting on a space, which live more naturally in the realm of functions.